# Android: How to throw an exception from Service.onCreate?

Tags: android, android-service, ioexception, oncreate

I have a `Service` that needs do some work in it's `onCreate`, like open a file. However, if there is an `IOException`, onCreate should fail, how can I indicate this to the caller? The method doesn't throw any exceptions. I've tried using `stopSelf()`, but apparently it has no effect in before the service is created, `onStartCommand()` is still called and the code fails later because the Service is not setup correctly.

```
public class MyService extends Service {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
     try {
        // do something
     } catch (IOException ex) {
        stopSelf(); // this does nothing
        // need to show that setting up the service failed
        return;
     }         
   }
   @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      // this shouldn't be called if there was an error in onCreate
   }
}
```

Comment: how about putting all the code on the `onStartcommand`?

Comment: Because the setup only needs to be done once

Comment: unfortunately you can't provide any sort of input with exception or return values, since the `Service`'s calls are made by the os and not any part of your activity. Maybe you can add a boolean flag to stop the service, which goes true on the `catch` statement and it stops the service on the `onStartCommand`

Comment: Thanks Tom, this would be the answer, except I can't approve a comment.